# iOS 9 - NSURLConnection fails on device (simulator works)

Tags: https, nsurlconnection, ios9

i have a problem in an iOS9 App with NSURLConnection. I am using the following coding to make the call to an https service:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                      returningResponse:&response
                                  error:&error];
```

I get an error showing me the following message:

```
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x15e55be0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."
```

I have added my domain to the info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>sub.mydomain.at</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

DO you have an hints why i get this failure ? To my suprise in the simulator everything works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your device connected to internet ? - check and double check it! Becasuse the error clearly says : Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Comment: hi.
problem solved. it seems that there was an issue with the flight mode that was previously on. restarting the phone did not help, but after resetting network settings everything worked fine again.